# Use another action instead of the shortcode API to display the last time a user logged in

Tags: shortcode, login, actions, oop

Here's my problem:

```
if ( !class_exists( 'printSecurity' ) ) {

    class printSecurity {

        public $constant_name_prefix = 'PRNSEC_';

        public function __construct() {

            define( $this->constant_name_prefix .'ROOTDIR', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) );
            add_action('admin_menu', array( $this, 'printSecurityMenu') );
            add_action( 'wp_login', array( $this, 'last_login'), 10, 2 );
            add_shortcode('lastlogin', array( $this, 'wpb_lastlogin') );

        }

        public function printSecurityMenu() {

            add_menu_page('Print security List',
                'Print security Crud',
                'manage_options',
                'printSecurityMain',
                array($this, 'printSecurityMain')
            );

        }

        public function last_login( $user_login, $user ) {
            update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'last_login', time() );
        }

        public function wpb_lastlogin() { 
            $user = wp_get_current_user();
            $last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login');
            var_dump($lastlogin);
            //die();
            $the_login_date = date('M j, Y h:i:s a', $last_login);


            if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] ) ) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
            } elseif ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] ) ) {
                $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
            } else {
                $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            }
            //return apply_filters( 'wpb_get_ip', $ip );
            var_dump($last_login);
            $user_cool = [
                'user_login'    => $user->user_login,
                'user_id'       => $user->ID,
                'user_ip'       => $ip,
                'user_log'      => $the_login_date,
                'user_rule'     => $user->roles[0],
            ];
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($user_cool as $value) {
                echo '<li>'.$value.'</li>';
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            //require_once(PRNSEC_ROOTDIR . 'printSecurityMain.php');
        }

        public function printSecurityMain() {

            require_once(PRNSEC_ROOTDIR . 'printSecurityMain.php');

        }

    }

}

global $printSecurity;
$printSecurity = new printSecurity();
```

This code only works if I use the shortcode API, but ideally, I want to fire it before the shortcode (page), as soon as I will get the admin page I want to display the access and data.

I have a couple of questions about it:

1. wp_login takes two arguments, $user_login and $user. Where do they come from?
2. If I will try to call the second function differently, for example:

   add_menu_page('Print List',
       'Print Crud',
       'manage_options',
       'wpb_lastlogin',
       array($this, 'wpb_lastlogin')
   );

And at the end of the wpb_lastlogin function

```
require_once(ROOTDIR . 'myadmintemplate.php');
```

and I will avoid adding the shortcode, it will return:

```
date() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given
```

Since $last_login will return NULL.

Is there something wrong that I do not quite understand about the last_login() function?

Comment: Are you trying to display the last login of the current user, the current author, or a particular user?

Comment: Just the current user

Comment: Ah, but the current author isn't always the current user. The current author is the author of the current post, not the current logged in user

Comment: How could it matter in this environment? I will post the entire code just to be more clear

Comment: because lets say I am user A and I logged in this afternoon, and I view a post by user B, who logged in this morning. Your code will say that user B logged in this afternoon. The function will give different values depending on which post or page you're on even though you stated it's always the time the current logged in user last logged in that you wanted

Comment: Additionally, what if there is no author at all? E.g. on an admin page. Using the author to retrieve your user meta is a major problem at the root of all your issues you're asking about, logically it makes no sense

Comment: You're saying that I should target another kind of object/user?

Comment: I kind of get it, I review my code in order to better explain what I want to achieve

Comment: If you want to show the last logged in time of the current logged in user, you should retrieve the user meta from the current logged in user. But instead, you retrieved the user meta from the author of the current post. E.g. the user that wrote the post, not the user the person is currently logged in as.

Comment: Cool! It makes sense.. feel free to post your solution in the meantime I will try to gather the documentation

Comment: Both get_usermeta()  and get_user_meta() are returing false..

Comment: Without seeing how you called those functions I have no idea what the problem was

Comment: I updated the question, and now I changed:

$last_login = get_the_author_meta('last_login') to $last_login = get_usermeta('last_login');

In that case the date return Jan 1, 1970 12:00:00 am because var_dump return respectively NULL and FALSE

Comment: Ooh, that's not how  `get_user_meta` works, `get_user_meta` is similar to `get_post_met`, you need to tell it which users meta, and how you want it. I'd recommend looking at the examples in the official doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store that information, WordPress already does this, and it does this across multiple sessions.

If you log in on your phone, and on your PC, then go to your user in WP Admin, you'll see them listed with a button to log you out on the other devices.

Additionally, WordPress stores the IP, expiration, and time the session began.

Here's a simple snippet that will reveal this information in the user edit screen:

```
<?php

add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'show_sessions_debug' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'show_sessions_debug' );

function show_sessions_debug( $user ) { ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="user_sessions_debug"><?php _e("Sessions"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <pre><?php var_dump( wp_get_all_sessions() ); ?></pre>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is brilliant, but it works with session instead of the login function

Comment: What about this one?

$user = wp_get_current_user();
   $last_login = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_login');
   
   $the_login_date = date('M j, Y h:i:s a', $last_login[0]);